# enable CORS over AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

we got an Angular2 App which is hosted on an S3 Bucket and sends calls to an Backend behind an API Gateway.

This works perfectly if we enable CORS by ourself at the API Gateway, but if we change something in our Backend and we deploy it with our `api_deploy.sh` skript, it usally resets some of the CORS configs.

```
aws apigateway create-deployment --rest-api-id XXXXXX --stage-name $1 --description "$2"
```

Is there a solution that we dont have to change it by ourself evrytime? I guess the Amazon CLI could help, but nothing seems to work so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rather use [CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) / [SAM](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model) to deploy your API Gateway.

After you enable CORS on your endpoints, try the following:

1. Export your API as a Swagger file with API Gateway Extensions (e.g. `swagger-stage.yaml`),
2. Create a template file that points to a swagger file on your local drive, e.g. `template.yaml`:

   ```
   AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
   Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
   Description: API deployment
   Resources:
     ApiGatewayApi:
       Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
       Properties:
         DefinitionUri: ./swagger-stage.yaml
         StageName: Staging
   Outputs:
     ApiUrl:
       Description: URL of the API endpoint
       Value: !Join
         - ''
         - - https://
           - !Ref ApiGatewayApi
           - '.execute-api.'
           - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
           - '.amazonaws.com/staging'
   ```
3. Deploy your stack to AWS CloudFormation with a few simple commands, e.g., `deploy.sh`:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   aws s3 mb --region eu-west-1 s3://cloudformation-uploads # only needed if bucket does not exist yet
   aws cloudformation package --template-file template.yaml --s3-bucket cloudformation-uploads --output-template-file template.pkg.yaml
   aws cloudformation deploy --template-file template.pkg.yaml --stack-name api-deploy-stack
   ```